# Changing number of fill levels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

In the code below, how do I raise the number of fill levels to, say, 4 or 5?

```
suppressMessages(library(ggmap))
data(crime)
houston.map <- get_map(location = geocode("Houston"),
                       zoom = 14)
print(ggmap(houston.map, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") +
        stat_density2d(data = crime,
                       aes(x = lon, y = lat, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..),
                       size = 2,
                       bins = 10,
                       geom = "polygon") +
        guides(alpha = F))
```

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: What does "raise the number of fill levels to, say, 4 or 5" mean exactly? Have you tried adjusting the `bins = ` parameter? Maybe that's what you're after.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes - I thought the question may not be clear (or even correct) the moment I hit the Ask button. What I wanted to do was to play with the number of items in the legend, and thought, perhaps wrongly, that it can be controlled by changing the fill levels or bin count. Adjusting bins is not doing it.